# listview and rating bar in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a list view , each item has a text view and a rating bar.
the Item layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="15sp"
      android:typeface="sans"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
  <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"

        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is GetView method of my ListAdapter:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

            RatingBar rate; 

            if (view == null)
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.QuestionListViewItemLayout, parent, false);
               // view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1, parent, false);

            question item = this[position];
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name).Text = item.text; 
            view.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ratingbar).Rating = item.userrate;
            RatingBar rb = view.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ratingbar);

            rb.RatingBarChange += (o, e) =>
            {
                item.userrate = System.Convert.ToInt32( e.Rating);
            };
            //view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SanadNumber).Text = item.sanadNumber.ToString();


            return view;
        }
```

in the line : "rb.RatingBarChange " when I change one of the ratingbars in my list view some other items are change. that delegate execute mor than one time each time I set rating for one of my rating bar.

so when I read " item.userrate" which edited by rating bar , there is not correct answer.

Comment: Anything you write in `getView()` without any condition would affect all views. Please read about adapters.

Comment: whould you please help me to find the condition to point current row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to have a list of Question(s) in my list view.
the question class is like this:

```
public  class question
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public int questionorder { get; set; }
        public int userrate { get; set; }

        public question()
        {
            userrate = 0;

        }

    }
```

now I need a "QuestionListViewItemLayout.axml" file for styling my list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:lineSpacingExtra="3dp"
      android:paddingRight="10dp"
      android:paddingTop="5dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="15sp"
      android:typeface="sans"now 
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
  <RatingBar android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"

        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

now I need a ListAdapter to manage Items in my List view, but first I have to create a Wrapper class to save views :

```
 public class ViewWrapper : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        View base1;
        RatingBar rate = null;
        TextView label = null;

      public  ViewWrapper(View base1)
        {
            this.base1 = base1;
        }

      public  RatingBar getRatingBar()
        {
            if (rate == null)
            {
                rate = base1.FindViewById<RatingBar>(Resource.Id.ratingbar);
            }

            return (rate);
        }

       public TextView getLabel()
        {
            if (label == null)
            {
                label = base1.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.name);
            }

            return (label);
        }
    }
```

this class created just for my question class and maybe you need to create your own wrapper similar to above code

it's time to create List adapter class :

```
public class QuestionListAdapter : BaseAdapter<question>
    {
        Activity context;
        List<question> list;
        public QuestionListAdapter(Activity _context, List<question> _list)
            : base()
        {
            this.context = _context;
            this.list = _list;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return list.Count; }
        }
        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }
        public List<question> GetList()
        {
            return list;
        }
        public override question this[int index]
        {
            get { return list[index]; }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

            ViewWrapper wrapper;
            RatingBar rate;    

            question item = this[position];
            if (view == null)
            {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.QuestionListViewItemLayout, parent, false);
                wrapper = new ViewWrapper(view);
                view.SetTag(Resource.Id.holder, wrapper);
                rate = wrapper.getRatingBar();

                rate.RatingBarChange += (o, e) =>
                {
                    RatingBar ratingBar = o as RatingBar;
                    int myPosition = (int)ratingBar.GetTag(Resource.Id.holder);
                    question model = list[myPosition];
                    model.userrate = System.Convert.ToInt32(e.Rating);
                };
            }
            else
            {

                wrapper = (ViewWrapper)view.GetTag(Resource.Id.holder);
                rate = wrapper.getRatingBar();

            }

            question model1 = list[position];

            wrapper.getLabel().Text = model1.text;
            rate.SetTag(Resource.Id.holder, position);
            rate.Rating = model1.userrate;

            return view;
        }
```

each time a view created I create a wrapper for it and put it into view's tag
Section : [if (view == null)]
and set an event for rating bar rate changes.

other time the view loads I get the tag and set the rating of rating bar form it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time GetView runs you create a new event handler for the event RatingBarChange, which creates a closure around the current "question" (item) instance (effectively keeping each item instance in memory and bound to each event handler instance). All these event handlers will fire each time and update each different item instance with the same value.

Your RatingBarChange event should have a single handler that gets the selected item and applies the rating.

Comment: so I should work on selected item of my listview. how can I find the rating bar of selected listview Item?