# Android - How to use ratingbar in listview to send data into mysql?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, ratingbar

anyone know how to send data using `ratingbar` in `listview`?

i have a same issues with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14769375/android-required-example-for-using-ratingbar-in-listview), and i tried to find the answer, but i still not solved it,,and also i've been checked all link their suggested before,

i want to know how can he solved the problem using `ViewBinder`, but i cant ***add comment*** because it's need 50++ rep to comment,

so i need more example how to send data from android into `MySQL` using `ratingbar` by `JSON id`

anyone can suggest me?

> Here is my code to display but not yet done to send data by user

`MainActivity.java`

```js
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    RatingBar rb1;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        new GetContacts().execute();
    }

    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String url = "http://zxccvvv.netne.net/send_data.php";
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = jsonObj.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String ask = c.getString("ask");

                        HashMap<String, String> pertanyaans = new HashMap<>();

                        pertanyaans.put("id", id);
                        pertanyaans.put("ask", ask);

                        contactList.add(pertanyaans);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"ask"}, new int[]{R.id.ask});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
}
```

`HttpHandler.java`

```js
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpHandler {

    private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

    public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            // read the response
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            response = convertStreamToString(in);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
    }

    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

`activity_main.xml`

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="flix.yudi.okhttp1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`list_item.xml`

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ask"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/rating"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?? You want to send the rate to your database?

Comment: i've created an app [like this](https://postimg.org/image/s8fukhx2d/487a79c5/) and this is my [database](https://postimg.org/image/5o4k3eulp/c498da12/), yes i want to send every rating of user into database, may you help me sir?

Comment: Yes. I'm writing an answer for you.

Comment: @MohammadZ should i put my android code sir?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has an Assignment that needs someone to solve it for him.

Comment: @k0sh i thought i've been wrote that i need an example, not really to solve my issues, althrough if someone really want to solve my question, im sure i cant put the pieces of code in my project, but thanks for your info

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should do this in your `getView()` method in your list adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null, false);
    }

    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    text.setText(data.get(position).getTitle());

    rateBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate);

    rateBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b) {
            // you have your rating in v
            // now you can put it in your database
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

**UPDATE 1**:
To have a custom view first you need write a class and extend `BaseAdapter`:

`MyAdapter.java`

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final List<HashMap<String,String>> data;

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final Context context;
private CustomTextView text;


public MyAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String,String>> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null, false);
    }

    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    rateBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);

    rateBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new     RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float v, boolean b)     {
            // you have your rating in v
            // now you can put it in your database
        }
    });

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should i put your answer above in my project? i dont have `getView()` method in my list adapter

Comment: I think it would be better for you to write your own adapter.

Comment: i dont know how to write my own adapter sir, all code i used, its all obtained by internet, and i need to finish this assignment of campus within 3 weeks, i dont have any idea to re-write my own adapter, it's annoying, haha

Comment: Ok. I'll try to give you some clue with an update to write your adapter

Comment: @MohammadZ you shouldn't really help him that much, we are not here to solve people assignments we are here to guide them in how to do it.

Comment: @k0sh about ur comment, do you have some reference code/link _how to do it_?